# Node JS GET API's not working with new data

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I am using Node JS and MYSQL. When I add new data to my project, it writes to the database. Then when I want to GET this data with another API, it doesn't come. When I try again after about a minute, it comes on. However, right after I send a request via Swagger, data comes from the outside (Postman or Panel) on my request again.

My simple Controller.

```
exports.GetAll = (req, res, next) => {
    ThisModel.GetAllSQL()
        .then((response) => {
            res.status(200).json(response[0]);
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.status(400).send();
            console.log('Senaryo listesi çekilirken bir hata meydana geldi: ' + error);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.then((response) => {
     res.status(200).json(response[0]);
 })
```

Judging from the line above, it looks like you're getting a list/array of data, but only returning the first item in the list `response[0]`.

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
 .then((response) => {
     res.status(200).json(response);
 })
```

Comment: The system works like this, actually an Array of 0.